# ASP.NET C# MVC Pass Values from Controller to cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to using Razor pages, so I have in the model directory a class with the following values:

```
public int Id { set; get; }
public string CustomerCode { set; get; }
public double Amount { set; get; }
```

Inside my controller (.cs file), I have the following:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     Customer objCustomer = new Customer();
     objCustomer.Id = 1001;
     objCustomer.CustomerCode = "C001";
     objCustomer.Amount = 900.78;
     return View();
 }
```

...now, I want to display the values via my Index.cshtml page, but when I run the application, I just get the actual code that I typed as oppose to the values:

...this is how have the .cshtml page setup:

```
@model Mvccustomer.Models.Customer

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<div>
    The customer id is : <%= Model.Id %> <br />
    The customer id is : <%= Model.CustomerCode %> <br />
    The customer id is : <%= Model.Amount %> <br />
</div>
```

...my question is, how do I get the values to display? Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [razor syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c).

Using your example:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<div>
    The customer id is : @Model.Id <br />
    The customer id is : @Model.CustomerCode <br />
    The customer id is : @Model.Amount <br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the value to the view in the return

```
return View(objCustomer);
```

This will allow the model binder to kick in, populating the values of your `@model` type with the values from the ActionResult's object.

If you are using razor instead of the `<%=` syntax, you should also replace those with the `@` razor syntax as shown in [Matt Griffiths' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49415649/1026459) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Complete solution to your problem:

Controller Action:   You need to send object to view from controller action

```
 public ActionResult Index()
     {
         Customer objCustomer = new Customer();
         objCustomer.Id = 1001;
         objCustomer.CustomerCode = "C001";
         objCustomer.Amount = 900.78;
         return View(objCustomer);
     }
```

View:    You need to use @ for Razor syntax

```
 @model Mvccustomer.Models.Customer

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

    <h2>Index</h2>
    <div>
        The customer id is : @Model.Id <br />
        The customer id is : @Model.CustomerCode <br />
        The customer id is : @Model.Amount <br />
    </div>
```

Comment: not sure why my answer down voted? Pls update with reason who down voted my answer